# Update bindsource and listview

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am working on a Delphi XE5 Firemonkey Mobil app.

I use FireDac for connection.

Just trying to do a simple query insert into sQlite database and update the listview with the inserted info.

```
  procedure TTabbedwithNavigationForm.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin

   DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.SQL.Text := 'insert into Invoice (Name) values(:newName)';
   DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.ParamByName('newName').AsString := 'test';
   DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.ExecSQL;
   BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Refresh;
   ////LinkFillControlToField1.BindList.FillList;
  end;
```

My problem is i am getting error.
error:= TFDQuery : Can not perform this operation on a closed dataset.
I have tried opening the dats set but no go.
Why will this not work ?

Comment: Why are you using the SELECT query to INSERT? Use a separate query for inserting, and one for deleting. See the Sample in the FireMonkey Mobile Code Snippets folder (it's the FireDACSQLLite demo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a record into a dataset with a select query like this:

```
DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Invoice';
DataModuel1.qSelectCustomers.Active := True;
DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.Append;
DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.FieldByName('Name').Value := 'test';
DataModule1.qSelectCustomers.Post;
```