# TListView record loading on demand

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, firemonkey, delphi-xe6, livebindings

I have made my application using TListView to show the main dataset as a listing as way to navigate the records. I have used LiveBindings with the Sync <-> * connection.

The major problem is that it loads the entire table into memory. That is slow most of the time, and now taking it to android even worst.

I have not found any example on how to page it. I am not using sql, I am using a custom DataSet (Aurelius) that retrieve the records on demand.

Since I have not found any documentation I have no starting point or code to share.

How to make TListView load records on demand?

PS. there is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19171302/576719) SO question, but that could be solved by SQL statement. I don´t have SQL available and I wonder if with the actual version of FMX that could be a better approach.

Comment: It should be possible to use `LiveBindings` to sync the loading from the database. See [updating-listview-item-attributes-on-the-fly-when-using-livebindings](http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/09/updating-listview-item-attributes-on-the-fly-when-using-livebindings/). See also [Mobile Tutorial: Using LiveBindings to Populate a ListView (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_LiveBindings_to_Populate_a_ListView_(iOS_and_Android)).

Comment: @LURD Thank you, I am using LiveBindings already, I have edited my question to state that, because I was supposing that LiveBindings would be the default standard for FMX. Using the Sync property of TListView does work, but it loads the entire DataSet, I want that it loads what is needed to display, or at least a small number (pages)

Comment: to the downvoter: please justify your down vote. Certainly you know the answer of my question, since you found it wrong.

Comment: Rather than focus on the control, try focusing on the actual problem. I would create a GUI class that holds a sub-set of the data and loads the data on demand. You can then bind any GUI control to this class and will make life easier should you decide to replace the `Listview` with a different control. You can then also re-use this class on a desktop app should you need to do so.

Comment: @Andy_D I believe this is right now out of reach of my knowledge. I have not found information enough about how the interaction of LiveBinding/ListView/BindSource occurs. I see there is not much on the ListView side, as you stated correctly.

Comment: @eelias There's a good article on the MGM (Model Gui Mediator) pattern here : http://www.andypatterns.com/files/91751232001357AndyBulkaModelGuiMediatorPattern.pdf Whilst using this approach will effectively replace live bindings, I've found live bindings to be slow and messy. I use an object persistence framework (tiOPF) for my applications and it comes with mediators for most of the common GUI controls and writing new ones is very straightforward.